# Teste the http response code and to some actions

Tags: postman

Is possible to call another collection if the response is as 401 ?

I have a snippet , that is going to check if the response is a 200 e reads the response. But if is a 401 i need to repost the authentication , is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can call a different request within the same collection using `postman.setNextRequest("request_name");` based on your `401` check.

[Here is a demo](http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/03/23/conditional-workflows-in-postman/) of that feature.